# ¿Como hago para saber si una cancion no fue añadida por ningun usuario?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Me piden la siguiente consulta: **Se quiere conocer la cantidad de canciones por artistas que no hayan sido agregadas a listas por ningun
usuario. Mostrar el nombre del artista y la cantidad, ordenado por mayor cantidad.**

Tengo estas 5 tablas:

```
artista (id(pk) , nombre, nombre_real, sigue_activo, pais_origen, anio_nacimiento)

usuario(nombre_completo, username , password, anio_inicio, pais_usuario)

cancion (nombre(PK),
artista(FK y PK) , duracion, descargas_actuales, anio_creacion)

en_lista (
nombre_usuario(FK y PK), 
nombre_cancion(FK y PK)
artista(FK y PK), anio_agregacion)

sigue(artista(FK Y PK) , 
nombre_usuario(FK y PK), anio_agregacion)
```

¿Como determino lo pedido en la consulta?
Mi idea era hacer una resta de conjuntos, restando el nombre de las canciones que son diferentes a las canciones de la tabla en_lista con el nombre de las canciones que son iguales a las que estan en la tabla en lista.

Mi codigo sería el siguiente:

```
      SELECT art.nombre, count(nombre_cancion) as cantidad_canciones
      FROM artista art
      JOIN en_lista AS el ON el.artista = art.id
      JOIN usuario AS u ON u.username = el.nombre_usuario
      JOIN cancion AS c ON c.nombre = el.nombre_cancion
      WHERE c.nombre = ((SELECT nombre
               FROM cancion
               WHERE c.nombre <> el.nombre_cancion)
               EXCEPT
               SELECT nombre 
               FROM cancion
               WHERE c.nombre= el.nombre_cancion)
               GROUP BY art.nombre
               ORDER BY cantidad_canciones DESC
               ;
```

Comment: y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: Edite la pregunta

Comment: Para este tipo de preguntas, procura incluir datos de prueba. Así mismo, cuéntanos por qué tu consulta no resuelve tu pregunta. Toda consulta SQL es correcta dependiendo de lo que busques! :) (A menos que la sintaxis esté mal, jeje)